# Does await block thread or pass on to caller or both?

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

There are 2 opinions and my experiment shows that both happens.

1. No. The await just move control to the caller.
2. Yes. The next statement to execute is the next statement after await.

Consider this code.

```
Public Shared Async Function getMarketDetailFromAllExchangesAsync() As Task
    For Each account In uniqueAccounts()
        Await account.Value.getMarketInfoAsync()
    Next
End Function
```

That code calls

```
Public Overrides Async Function getMarketInfoAsync() As Task
    'readbalances()
    Dim json = Await CookieAwareWebClient.downloadString1Async("https://api.lbkex.com/v1/ticker.do?symbol=all")

    Dim ja = JArray.Parse(json)

    For Each jo In ja
        Dim symbol = jo("symbol").ToString
        Dim base1 = ""
...
        Dim bidaskTuple = Await getBidAskFromDepthArrayWithURLAsync("https://api.lbkex.com/v1/depth.do?symbol=" + symbol + "&size=1", "bids", "asks", CDbl(jo(LOW)), CDbl(jo(HIGH)))
        jo(BID) = bidaskTuple.Item1
        jo(ASK) = bidaskTuple.Item2
    Next

    typicalGetMarketInfoWithJsonStringAlreadyReady(ja.ToString, "", BID, ASK, HIGH, LOW, VOLUME, LAST, "https://www.lbank.info/exchange.html?asset={quote}&post={base}", "", BASE, QUOTE, "", 0, "")
    'getOrders()
End Function
```

After

```
        Dim bidaskTuple = Await getBidAskFromDepthArrayWithURLAsync("https://api.lbkex.com/v1/depth.do?symbol=" + symbol + "&size=1", "bids", "asks", CDbl(jo(LOW)), CDbl(jo(HIGH)))
```

the next code called is

```
        jo(BID) = bidaskTuple.Item1
```

Which is the next statement.

However, in this code

```
Public Async Sub finRepeatOrderingSync()
    Dim i = Await finRepeatOrderingAsync()
    Dim b = i 'can't get it till we got i
End Sub
```

Same thing. After Await finRepeatOrderingAsync that dim b=i is not called yet.

However, the code that run finRepeatOrderingSync finish

This code

```
Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdGroupRepeat.Click
    startAndStopClickingButton(sender, Sub()
                                           finRepeatOrderingSync() ' this one never end
                                           Dim b = 1
                                       End Sub)
End Sub
```

is done.

I actually want the opposite result. Each account in uniqueAccounts should have its own task (or thread but await and sync is actually single threaded right?).

On the other hand, I want to reenable all buttons in my control after finRepeatOrderingSync finish.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of code and a lot of discussion in your question that really seems to boil down to how this code executes:

```
Public Async Function Foo() As Task
    Dim i = Await GetValueAsync()
    Dim b = i
End Function
```

A call to `Foo` will call in to `GetValueAsync` and then return to the caller of `Foo` while `GetValueAsync` is running and only continue in the `Foo` method when there is a result.

From an step-by-step point-of-view it is the same as this code:

```
Public Sub Foo()
    Dim i = GetValue()
    Dim b = i
End Sub
```

What I understand from your last three paragraphs, which seems to be the most important part of your question, you want to execute all of the `getMarketInfoAsync` calls simultaneously yet await the calls to all of them. That's easy to do.

First up, though, your code structure and naming conventions are not what you'd typically see in a .NET project. I've coded up a more typical scenario and I'll leave it to you to translate back to what you're doing.

To start with, I've defined up these simple classes:

```
Public Class MarketInfo
    Public Account As Account
End Class

Public Class Account
End Class
```

Now, I'm going to assume that you have these two methods available and working correctly:

```
Private Shared Function UniqueAccounts() As List(Of Account)
Public Shared Async Function GetMarketInfoAsync(account As Account) As Task(Of MarketInfo)
```

Now your original method, updated to suit these changes, looks like this:

```
Public Shared Async Function GetMarketDetailFromAllExchangesAsync() As Task
    For Each account In UniqueAccounts()
        Await GetMarketInfoAsync(account)
    Next
End Function
```

Based on how I said the operations occur you'd call this with `Await GetMarketDetailFromAllExchangesAsync()` somewhere and the code would execute against each `account`, one-by-one, without blocking the calling thread.

You want to be able to call all of them at once and return all the results. Here's how:

```
Public Shared Async Function GetMarketDetailFromAllExchangesAsync() As Task(Of MarketInfo())
    Return Await Task.WhenAll(UniqueAccounts().Select(Function (account) GetMarketInfoAsync(account)).ToArray())
End Function
```

Now you'd just call that like this:

```
Dim info As MarketInfo() = Await GetMarketDetailFromAllExchangesAsync()
```

Comment: It's working. I didn't do it your way. I did it differently, but the concept is the same. I am using when all. Thanks

Comment: what is select? is that linq?

Comment: Two answers answering 2 different aspect of the question. I selected @Aconfusedsimpleton answer because he has only 82 points. I wonder if this is proper? You don't need points right?

Comment: @user4951 - Careful doing it your way - there be dragons. Yes, `Select` is LINQ. There's no drama either way with points. You should just select the answer that you think future readers should look at.

Comment: @user4951 You should select whichever one you think answers the question better, regardless of the number of points the respective responders have.

Comment: They're both good. However, I upvoted both. However, you should notice that @aconfused answer actually answer the question right in the first paragraph. Your answer, while also good, adds value to his answer.

Comment: Actually your answer also make it clear. I don't know. The select thingy, it's kind of hard to debug if things go wrong right?

Comment: Okay you give more insight. Hmm... The answers are almost equally good though

Answer (score 1):

Await does not block a thread and always passes control to the caller, that's it's purpose.

> This code

```
Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdGroupRepeat.Click
    startAndStopClickingButton(sender, Sub()
                                       finRepeatOrderingSync() ' this one never end
                                       Dim b = 1
                                   End Sub)
End Sub
```

> is done.

Your event handler is run synchronously because it never awaits anything, Async code should always be called by Async code. have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

> I actually want the opposite result. Each account in uniqueAccounts should have its own task (or thread but await and sync is actually single threaded right?).

For CPU bound work that you want done on a separate thread you should use Task.Run(), documentation can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.8

> On the other hand, I want to reenable all buttons in my control after finRepeatOrderingSync finish.

How can I do that?

You can do this by disabling the buttons, then awaiting the result of whatever CPU bound work you want done and then reenabling the buttons:

```
Private Async Sub Button2_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.click
    DisableButtons()
    Dim Result As Object = Await Task.Run(Function() SomeFunction)
    EnableButtons()

End Sub
```

Comment: So the event handler must be async? Is it possible to do this if the event handler is not async?

Comment: If the eventHandler calls Async code then the handler itself should be Async. If you don't want the handler to be Async then you shouldn't call 'SomeFunction' Asynchronously (in the example above). In that case you simply call 'SomeFunction' without Task.Run

This achieves the same result (buttons disabled while doing work) but the difference is that all the work is done on the main thread (and thus blocks it)

Is there any specific reason why you don't want the eventHandler to be ASync?

Comment: Note that 'SomeFunction' itself does not need to be an Async function. Task.Run Takes care of running it Asynchronously on a background thread. It creates a taskobject that you can await. Thus the event handler returns control to the main thread until the CPU bound work is completed, so your UI stays responsive

Answer (score 0):

I am summarizing both answers. This is what I did to make the enable button happens after the await

```
Private Async Sub RepeatTheWholeThing_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdGroupRepeat.Click
    Await startAndStopClickingButton2(sender, Async Function() As Task
                                                  Await finRepeatOrderingAsync() ' this one never end
                                                  Dim b = 1
                                              End Function)
End Sub

Public Async Function startAndStopClickingButton2(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal SomeSub As System.Func(Of Task)) As Task
    startClickingButton(sender)
    Await SomeSub.Invoke()
    stopClickingButton(sender)
End Function
```

This is what I did to make the accounts load almost simultaneously

```
Public Shared Async Function getMarketDetailFromAllExchangesAsync() As Task
    Dim taskList = New List(Of Task)
    For Each account In uniqueAccounts()
        Dim newtask = account.Value.getMarketInfoAsync()
        taskList.Add(newtask)
    Next
    Await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray)

    Dim b = 1
End Function
```

The idea is the same as the @enigmativity idea. However, I use for next instead of select. Hence it's easier to debug.